# Finding GCD with C

Tags: c, greatest-common-divisor

My question is when i type in something like "10 0" i get 10 as GCD. I thought the programming would not execute if i typed in 0 or shoe GCD as 0 and not 10. I have tried with other integers and it seems to work except for 0.

```
  int m, n, remainder;

  printf ("Enter two intergers: ");
  scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);

  while (n != 0 )
  {     
    remainder = m % n;    
    m = n;    
    n = remainder;
  }    

  printf("GCD: %d\n\n", m);
```

Comment: `0 % 10` is `0`, no remainder, thus `0` *is* divisible by `10`. In fact, `0` is divisible by *any* non-zero integer without remainder. `gcd(0, x)` is `x`, this is not an error.

Comment: [gcd(10, 0)](http://calculus.nipissingu.ca/gcd/gcd.html) is `10`.  What were you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning 'n' 0 and therefore the loop is never executed. m stays as 10

Answer (score 0):

Because when n=0, loop is not entered. That prints the exact value `m` has. A program wouldn't solve any problem magically until you handle it.

Comment: Try reading the citation carefully. Is the condition you highlighted met for `gcd(x,0)`, `x != 0`?

Comment: I might be an old man by now, but I still remember the time when calculating-with-fractions were taught in primary school. And the reading comprehension was--how shall I put it--slightly higher, too. *sigh*

Comment: oh my mistake. I must have been high :/